# error creating overlay mount to a nfs mount

Tags: docker

I am using docker version 17.05.0.

Instead of using the Docker Root Dir: `/var/lib/docker`, I am using a directory `/u01` which is mounted on the VM using an NFS share.

Docker Root Dir: /u01/docker

Storage Driver: overlay2

```
# cat daemon.json
{
  "data-root": "/u01/docker",
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Now when I am starting the daemon, the docker pull command is working fine but when I am trying to build an image, its throwing the following error:

```
Step 2/14 : MAINTAINER RK
error creating overlay mount to /u01/docker/overlay2/f5aebc4aa90797ccfab90bfb17a44314041b4694b26aa5a1e82eba95384f9924-init/merged: invalid argument
```

Not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Have you checked that selinux are disabled? https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a couple of things:

1. overlay2 is the default storage driver, but as you can see in [docker storage driver documentation](http://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver), is valid only for **xfs with ftype=1, ext4**
   Maybe, your `/u01/docker` is in another filesystem.
2. If your `/u01/docker` is a xfs with ftype=1 or ext4 type, check selinux are disabled.

In order to check backing system is compatible with your overlay2, you can execute:

```
$ docker info

Containers: 0
Images: 0
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
<output truncated>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be running docker with an NFS server as the backing filesystem. Even if you could get it to work, it would be slow and the problem of distributing images to multiple hosts has already been solved with registry servers and reusable layers.

The overlay2 filesystem itself is documented as requiring xfs with ftype=1 or ext4 as the backing filesystem, not NFS.

Where you can use NFS is with the volumes mounted into containers for persistent data. These volumes would exist outside of the container and would not be saved to the registry, so pushing those to NFS makes sense. Here's a few examples of different ways to mount a volume with NFS:

```
  # create a reusable volume
  $ docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=nfs \
      --opt o=nfsvers=4,addr=nfs.example.com,rw \
      --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
      foo

  # or from the docker run command
  $ docker run -it --rm \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=nfs.example.com\",volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
    foo

  # or to create a service
  $ docker service create \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=nfs.example.com\",volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
    foo

  # inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  volumes:
    nfs-data:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: nfsvers=4,addr=nfs.example.com,rw
        device: ":/path/to/dir"
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the workaround surprisingly was to restrict the number of 'RUN' docker building commands/layers, since if the number surpassed 60 layers/commands, it always ended up with that missing 'merged' folder error, no matter what was the contents of the command, even simple command such as `RUN ls -la` ended up with that error, if the total number of such/any commands was higher than about 60, strange. `Merged` subfolder was always missing, though even when I automatically generated all the merged subfolders, always was created on the fly a new layer with a new hash, which was missing that subfolder.

Comment: can u add more details please? which commands used you to solution it?

Comment: It is a workaround, meaning that if you had more times the command/word "RUN" in your dockerfile than 60 times, it stopped to work, so I worked it around when I had more than 60 RUN commands in my file, I made 60 run commands into 30 commands by contatenating commands so two run commands `RUN ls -la` , `RUN date` I merged into a single RUN command like this  `RUN ls -la && date`

Comment: Thanks @Evan Carrol for a grammar correction of a "working workaround" could sound like a trusim, though it was somehow an abbreviation of typing "for me working approach was a workaround"

Comment: Even if you typed that it would be redundant. How would a "non-working approach that was a workaround" be a valuable contribution? ;)